# Split a string in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function where I get some values dynamically and I send them to other function.

```
function sample(){
//some code here
var latlong1=//some value;
var latlong2=//some value;
fnSplitString(latlong1,latlong2);
}
```

I am sending these values to a function say

```
function fnSplitString(l1,l2)
{
alert("Latlong1::::"+l1);
alert("LatLong2::::"+l2);
var splitStringLatLong=l1.split(",");
alert("split1"+splitStringLatLong[0]);
alert("split2"+splitStringLatLong[1]);
}
```

here my 'l1' and 'l2' are alerting the values properly as.

```
Latlong1::::lat=78.23456,long=26.56789
Latlong2::::lat=74.57585,long=22.67890
```

I want to extract only the numeric values from these two strings. Hence I tried splitting it first till comma. But the split is not working at all. I do not get any alert message. Where is the mistake? And how do I extract only numeric from the string?

Comment: This works: `"lat=78.23456,long=26.56789".split(',')`. Please check the browser console, the alert very likely does not execute because there is a error somewhere.

Comment: I cleared the browser history. Still it doesnt alert me.

Comment: Syntax error. You have a semicolon in the middle of function declaration.

Comment: Its a typing mistake here . I have edited it. Still doesnt work.

Comment: I created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/T9LMX/ that seems to work at producing the alerts. All that needs doing is to remove the text.

Comment: I didn't mean the browser history: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: @mfdoran hah, that's funny, i did the exact same thing: [http://jsfiddle.net/q9A8q/](http://jsfiddle.net/q9A8q/) , seems to work over here as well.

Comment: @mfdoran :thank you for your efforts. But I just get alerts of the string but not the alerts after splitting.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra semi-colon at the end of the first line of your fnSplitString definition.

Try removing that and see if it works. Corrected code below.

```
function fnSplitString(l1,l2) 
{
   alert("Latlong1::::"+l1);
   alert("LatLong2::::"+l2);
   var splitStringLatLong=l1.split(",");
   alert("split1"+splitStringLatLong[0]);
   alert("split2"+splitStringLatLong[1]);
}
```

Comment: Its a typing mistake here . I have edited it. Still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution but this works:

```
var temp  = 'lat=78.23456,long=26.56789';
var lat =   temp.substring(4, temp.indexOf(",long"));
var long =  temp.substring(temp.indexOf("g")+2, temp.length);
alert(lat);
alert(long);
```

Comment: Definitely not the best. The string `lat` and `long` might change in future. Nice effort for a first timer though. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think regex is the simplest solution.

I'm not very strong in this, but here goes:

```
var str = "lat=78.23456,long=26.56789";
var s = str.match(/(?:\d*\.)?\d+/g);
alert("string1: "+s[0]+", string2: "+s[1]);
```

The result is an array of strings, but you can convert it to whatever you want.